# PHP use password and salt to get IV and Key alternative to C# Rfc2898DeriveBytes (AES256)

Tags: c#, php, cryptography, pbkdf2

I want to regenerate my IV and Key from the password and salt I have stored.
In my C# program I do It in the following way :

```
//passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);
var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
```

The code for this is PHP returning is return a different IV and Key :

```
<?php
include("enctest_inc.php");

$password = "mypassword";
$salt = "mysalthereitis";

$hasher = "SHA256";
$iterations = 1000;
$keysize = 256;
$ivsize = 128;

$out = pbkdf2($hasher, $password, base64_decode($salt), $iterations, ($keysize+$ivsize)/8, true);

// split key and IV
$key = substr($out, 0, $keysize/8);
$iv = substr($out, $ivsize/8);

// print for demonstration purposes
echo base64_encode($key);
echo "<br>";
echo base64_encode($iv);
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';

echo 'KEY : LNY893Wa00onNQh4ignFdjaVkg6GdxomMZoR/axB+Mw='; //KEY FROM SSH PROGRAM WHICH IS THE RIGHT RETURN;
echo '<br>';
echo 'IV : //QxQj7PDMRE1YUVo+mJvQ==' //IV FROM SSH PROGRAM WHICH IS THE RIGHT RETURN;
```

I really wonder where the problem lays or how to debug this ?

The settings are in both PHP and C# the same :

PHP CODE :

```
$hasher = "SHA256";
$iterations = 1000;
$keysize = 256;
$ivsize = 128;
```

C# CODE :

```
string random_string_pwd = "mypassword";
byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(random_string_pwd);

//var random_salt = new ClientTools();
//string random_string_salt = random_pwd.RndStrings(15);
string random_string_salt = "mysalthereitis";
byte[] Salt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(random_string_salt);

// Hash the password with SHA256
passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);
AES.KeySize = 256;
AES.BlockSize = 128;

var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
```

Comment: Can you give some example output strings?

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you Base64 decode the salt but it is not base64 encoded:
`base64_decode($salt)`

In C# you just get the bytes of the salt:
`byte[] Salt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(random_string_salt);`

In PHP you are using SHA256
In C# you are using MSN Rfc2898DeriveBytes which uses SHA1:
[Rfc2898DeriveBytes Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx) specifies: using a pseudo-random number generator based on HMACSHA1.
Using SHA256 on `password bytes` does not fix the MSN rfc2898derivebytes. This is an MSN issue since it does not allow the HAMC to be specified.

The solution is to change the PHP to just get the string bytes as data, not to try and Base64 decode something that is not Base64 encoded.

1. At a minimum do the same thing in each language
2. If you need to use the MSN Rfc2898DeriveBytes then change the PHP HMAC to SHA1.
3. Do not Base64 decode a string that is not Base64 encoded, this will often fail. In fact Base64 decoding mysalthereitis"

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this question. Did not notice the base64_decode error, also thanks for that. 1. I was believing i was doing the same in both C# and PHP 2. i changed it to sha1 and removed the base64 decode but still a different result. Interesting I really was believing it changed to sha256 with passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);

Comment: @AVGG How about you remove that `passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);` step, because that's also not in the PHP code.

Comment: Also changed this line from $iv = substr($out, $ivsize/8); to $iv = substr($out, $keysize/8, $ivsize/8); now its working. But I wonder if removing SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes); does not creates weak security, easily crackable passwords..

Comment: @AVGG Be sure to post your own answer with the full working code. And no, that one additional SHA-256 does absolutely nothing to improve security if you have a large iteration count for PBKDF2.

Comment: Thanks, 2 questions left why do i need to use sha1, i dont see it specified in the C# source anywhere ? And what is the problem with MSN rfc2898derivebytes zaph is talking about.

Comment: Would it also be save to store the key and iv in the program itself ? I guess not since .net are easy to decompile ?!

Comment: The MSN `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` uses SHA1, see the link in my answer so you need to use SHA1 i the PHP code to match.

Comment: The iv is not secret, the key is. It comes down to how much work an attacker will do and how sophisticated they are. You need to explicitly define who attackers might be and the value of what is being secured. Unless you have an HSM or equivalent the key is always going to be available some point. You can reduce the exposure but that is about all.